# Delete system cache on android 6.0

Tags: android

I'm using method `freeStorageAndNotify()` with permission `android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE` to delete system cache of all installed applications. But the method started throwing `InvocationTargetException` from the android marshmallow 6.0 version. 
After googling the issues I found the same issue as reported here:
[Android M reflection method freeStorageAndNotify exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31989637/android-m-reflection-method-freestorageandnotify-exception)
So here the conclusion was, `freeStorageAndNotify()` stopped working since google has raised the method's signature level now to signature|system.

But now the question is how other third-party apps like 'Clean master' are still able to delete system cache of all installed applications by taking accessibility permission from the user for 6.0 devices?

Comment: Clean Master app doesn't use accessibility permissions.

Comment: Have you tried [peeking](http://www.decompileandroid.com/) into the APK?

Comment: Have you tried to delete the cache folder directly? (Probably you need the read/write storage access permission, but i'm not sure you can do it)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that 'Clean master' actually uses Accessibility Permissions to clean installed apps cache.
But, if you're interested, this goal can be achieved by using `AccessibilityService` in your application.
Within your class that extends `AccessibilityService` you have this callback:

```
    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent aEvent) {
       AccessibilityNodeInfo rootNode = aEvent.getSource();
       //...
    }
```

Here you can invoke 
`rootNode.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId()` 
or 
`rootNode.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByText()`, 
it will return all matching `AccessibilityNodeInfo` objects (sub-nodes) in tree. Then, you just need to detect which of them is `Button` (`node.getClassName()`) and call `subNode.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK)`.

On Android M, you first need to to open system's `App Info` screen (you can find instructions here [How can I start android application info screen programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421527/how-can-i-start-android-application-info-screen-programmatically)) for the concrete app and, by the scheme described above, perform sequential clicks on the buttons "Storage" —> "Clear cache".

In order to clear cache for all installed apps you probably have to iterate through the all installed apps (`List<ApplicationInfo> installedApplications = context.getPackageManager.getInstalledApplications(0);`)
and repeat the procedure mentioned above.

Answer (score -1):

The system cleaner I'm using has access to the STORAGE permissions. This permission gives the app authority to clear any data in the shared external storage directory.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission_group.html#STORAGE

I don't think any 3rd party app can actually clear system cache anymore unless the device is rooted and the app is designed for rooted devices.

[image: clean Master permission]

[image: clean Master asking for permission]

Comment: I know that. My question is how "Clean Master" app can able to do it by taking accessibility permission from user.

Comment: Clean Master only takes the STORAGE permission.

Comment: Clean Master expressly asks to access the STORAGE PERMISSION

Comment: If you look at the full set of permissions, Clean Master doesn't use Accessibility permissions at all.

Comment: Clean master asks for  Accessibility permission  from the user, when you need to clear the cache files.

Answer (score -4):

those apps only do the same thing all the time. use it on an old device and a new device the results are the same. the only help i have seen is that they can kill or restart some background processes, not to clean the cache. therefore no API can restrict their trick..