# How to take CLEAR_APP_CACHE permission in Android Marshmallow at runtime?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

**Code**:

```
void clearCache() {

    if (mClearCacheObserver == null) {
        mClearCacheObserver = new CachePackageDataObserver();
    }

    PackageManager mPM = getPackageManager();

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    final Class[] classes = {Long.TYPE, IPackageDataObserver.class};

    Long localLong = Long.valueOf(CACHE_APP);


    try {
        Method localMethod =
                mPM.getClass().getMethod("freeStorageAndNotify", classes);

        localMethod.setAccessible(true);
        // Start of inner try-catch block

        try {
            localMethod.invoke(mPM, localLong, mClearCacheObserver);

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.getCause().printStackTrace();
        }

        // End of inner try-catch block

    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e1) {

        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

**Logcat**:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10206 nor current process has android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE.
     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
     at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.freeStorageAndNotify(IPackageManager.java:5081)
     at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.freeStorageAndNotify(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2500)
     at android.content.pm.PackageManager.freeStorageAndNotify(PackageManager.java:4710)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.onexsoftech.clearcacheapp.MainActivity.clearCache(MainActivity.java:278)
     at com.onexsoftech.clearcacheapp.MainActivity.insertDummyContactWrapper1(MainActivity.java:495)
     at com.onexsoftech.clearcacheapp.MainActivity.insertDummyContact(MainActivity.java:472)
```

Comment: is that code working before marshmallow devices

Comment: yes it is working well in pre marshmallow

Answer (score 8):

Prior to Android 6.0, [`CLEAR_APP_CACHE` had a `protectionLevel` of `dangerous`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-5.1.1_r29/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml), so ordinary SDK apps could request it in the manifest.

As of Android 6.0, [`CLEAR_APP_CACHE` has a `protectionLevel` of `signature|privileged`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-6.0.1_r66/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml). Ordinary Android apps cannot hold this permission. You can only hold this permission if your app is signed with the firmware's signing key or you are installed on the privileged system partition.

Comment: could you provide an example of how to use this permission

Answer (score 6):

From Android M -> CLEAR_APP_CACHE, Protection level: system|signature

> Android 6.0 does not change the behavior of normal permissions (all
>   non-dangerous permissions including normal, system, and signature
>   permissions).

So it is not possible to ask for that permission in runtime. To be more precise

> A signature|system permission, meaning that it can only be held by
>   apps that are signed with the firmware's signing key or are installed
>   on the system partition (e.g., by a rooted device user). From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31989637/android-m-reflection-method-freestorageandnotify-exception) stackoverflow Q/A.

Docs:
https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/runtime_perms.html#affected-permissions

Answer (score -3):

Add Permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE"/>
```

Make a Constant for Request Code.

**Constants.java**

```
public static final int REQUEST_CODE_FOR_PERMISSION = 501;
```

Request Permission :-

```
public static void requestPermissionForClearCache(Activity activity) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, Manifest.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE}, Constatnts.REQUEST_CODE_FOR_PERMISSION);
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE}, Constatnts.REQUEST_CODE_FOR_PERMISSION);
        }
    }
}
```

Override Below method in Fragment.

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == Constatnts.REQUEST_CODE_FOR_PERMISSION && grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // permission was granted successfully
    } else {
        // permission was NOT granted successfully
    }
}
```

Comment: Why downvoted this answer? Full Explanation is described.

Comment: Except that it is wrong for this specific permission. Plus, you do not declare system permissions yourself via `<permission>`.